# Angular 5 gives error - Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”)

Tags: angular5, playframework-2.6

I am getting the following error in my `Angular5` applications.

```
Error: call to Function() blocked by CSP
vendor.bundle.js:50077:40
bind_constructFunctionN self-hosted:1214:16 Function self-hosted:1132:24 evalExpression
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/vendor.bundle.js:50077:40
jitStatements
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/vendor.bundle.js:50095:12
../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype._interpretOrJit
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/vendor.bundle.js:50678:20
../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype._compileTemplate
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/vendor.bundle.js:50606:43
../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents/<
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/vendor.bundle.js:50505:56
forEach self-hosted:5732:9 ../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/vendor.bundle.js:50505:9
../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents/<
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/vendor.bundle.js:50375:13
then
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/vendor.bundle.js:16489:77
../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/vendor.bundle.js:50374:16
../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js/JitCompiler.prototype.compileModuleAsync
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/vendor.bundle.js:50268:32
../../../platform-browser-dynamic/esm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js/CompilerImpl.prototype.compileModuleAsync
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/vendor.bundle.js:79292:34
../../../core/esm5/core.js/</PlatformRef.prototype.bootstrapModule
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/vendor.bundle.js:57045:16
../../../../../src/main.ts
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/main.bundle.js:1179:1
__webpack_require__
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/inline.bundle.js:55:12
[0]
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/main.bundle.js:1188:18
__webpack_require__
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/inline.bundle.js:55:12
webpackJsonpCallback
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/inline.bundle.js:26:23
<anonymous>
http://localhost:9000/assets/ui/main.bundle.js:1:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”).
localhost:9000:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). Source: /* You can add global styles to this fil....
localhost:9000:1
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). Source: call to eval() or related function blocked by CSP.
vendor.bundle.js:50077
```

The Angular application sends the `Content-Security-Policy

default-src 'self'` header in initial `GET` request but the page doesn't get loaded. I suppose Angular code is trying to fetch files from some source outside of `self`. However, from the stack, I see that the requests are only being sent to `localhost` which I suppose should be `self`. Why isn't the code working then?

My setup is a bit different though. I have compiled all the Angular code and moved its `js` files to `public` folder of `play` framework (my server).

Comment: The issue seem to be not the source but that browser didn't allow use of `Function` to avoid XSS attacks. I could make the code work by adding the following in `application.conf` in `play`. However, I am not sure if this is the right way as I suppose I am allowing  use of `eval` and `Function` which might allow XSS attacks. Is this the right way considering that it is not my code which is calling `Function` at the first place. `contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'self' ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"`

Comment: It seems that the code generated by Angular cli uses eval and Function. So probably, for the moment, relaxing CSP policy is the only workaround. - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6872

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seem to be not the source but that browser didn't allow use of Function to avoid XSS attacks. I could make the code work by adding the following in `application.conf` in `play` (server). However, I am not sure if this is the right way as I suppose I am allowing use of eval and Function which might allow XSS attacks. Is this the right way considering that it is not my code which is calling Function at the first place. `contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'self' ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"`

It seems that the code generated by Angular cli uses eval and Function. So probably, for the moment, relaxing CSP policy is the only workaround. - github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6872

Happy to accept other answers

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error, but after building with `ng build --prod`, I didn't need `'unsafe-eval'` anymore, without `--prod` I still need `'unsafe-eval'`. Running Flask/Angular 5.0.3